# Getting specific objects with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models for users, companies, surveys, questions and answers.

- The company has a relation of `has_many` surveys
- The company has a relation of `has_many` users
- The survey  has a relation of `has_many` questions
- The question has a relation of `has_many` answers
- The user has a relation of `has_many` answers

So according to that the company has some users and some surveys. These surveys has some questions and each question has some answers, the answers come from certain users.

What I want to do is to check for the last survey and get the specific users whom not answerd any question on the survey.

I tried to accomplish that using each loops, to loop through the company users then loop through each user question from the last survey then loop in its answer to get the users that answered at least one question and inserting them into an array, after these loops I get the difference between the two arrays to get only the users whom did not' answer any question. This method works well but I think there is a better way to do that, maybe using scopes or if there is nested scopes. I just want a clean and straightforward way other than this looping way. By the way the question needs a better title :)

```
current_company = Company.find(current_user.company_id)
has_answer = false

company_users = []
users_whom_answered = []
current_company.users.each {|u| company_users << u}

current_company.users.each do |user|
  Survey.last.questions.each do |question|
    question.answers.each do |answer|
      if answer.user_id == user.id
        has_answer = true
        users_whom_answered << user
        break
      end
    end
    break if has_answer
  end
end
result = company_users - users_whom_answered
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

```
last_survey_id = Survey.last.id

scope = User.includes(answers: :questions)
scope = scope.where(answers: { user_id: nil })
scope = scope.where(questions: { survey_id: last_survey_id })
```

I'm not sure if it will retrieves Users who did not answer at least 1 question OR if it will retrieve Users who did not answer any question at all..